# Log function with surf() in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d

I would like to draw the following in 3D in matlab.

```
X = [1 2 4 8 16 32 64];
Y = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
Z = [1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
     1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
     1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
     1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
     1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
     1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
     1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
     1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
     1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
     1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;] ;
surf(X,Y,Z);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[ 1 2 4 8 16 32 64]);
zlabel('Z');
ylabel('Y');
xlabel('X');
```

- I want the function to have log scale at the same time the X labels have values of X which
  are     [1 2 4 8 16 32 64].
- I want also to make circle around the
  values that are intersected with X, Y, and Z  because if you can see from X values isn't corresponding to values in the graph
- Specify colors for  each value of Y axis instead of having coloring range

[image]

Anyone can help even if I have to use another function ?.

I did this attempt:

```
  X = [1 2 4 8 16 32 64];
    Y = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
    Z = [1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
         1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
         1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
         1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
         1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
         1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
         1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
         1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
         1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;
         1 1.8 3.5 5.09 5.5 5.8 5.9;] ;
    surf(log(X),Y,Z);

    zlabel('Z');
    ylabel('Y');
    xlabel('X');
    set(gca, 'xscale', 'log')
```

The result is below, and as you can see the values on X-axis isn't right 
[image]

Now, also Y axis not starting from one, however the first value is started from 1

Comment: A log scale will make an exponential look linear, but certainly not make your curve 'go down'. Can you make this clearer?

Comment: I updated the question and Now you can check how the log affected the results.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `surf(X,Y,log(Z))`?

Comment: The problem will be the same in all cases, whether it's log(Z) or log(X)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XLABEL=[ 1 2 4 8 16 32 64]
surf(log(X),Y,Z);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',XLABEL);
set(gca,'XTick',log(XLABEL));
```

`XTick` gives the location of the labels, which should be in logarithmic scale, but the label itself ('XTickLabel') should not be logarithmic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how I can make each value in x axis corresponding to exactly a line of a graph ?. For example, the first figure, 4 on x-axis should be corresponding to the start of green area.

Comment: If I plot this, it is aligned. Does it look different on your PC? I don't really understand what you are trying to change on the x-axis.

Comment: You have 6 colors with 7 points. So Now, 1 and 2 on x-axis has same color which is navy. I want something like lines perpendicular on x axis from points of the colored lines.

Comment: No, the interval [0 1] is navy, the interval [2 4] lightblue, the interval [4 8] is green etc...

Comment: Thanks for your reply ans help so much.

Comment: Try `ylim([1,10])`, it makes the x-axis better readable because it's aligned with the first data row.

Comment: Will it be possible in that case to have colorbar for values in Z, because Z are labeled differently than normal colorbar which has range from 2:16 in that case

Comment: I don't see any 2:16 range. `colorbar` adds a colorbar.

Comment: if you call colorbar(); , by default it will add colorbar whose range is 2:16. I solved this issue by the following:
hcb = colorbar(); set(hcb,'YTickLabel',[5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40]); where I set the Zlim by: zlim([0,40]); and Now it's fine
Thanks so much again for your help